# Exchange EWS - How to retrieve occurrence from master event on specific date?

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I want to retrieve the occurrence (ItemID) from a recurring master calendar event on a specific date (I have the date of the occurrence and the recurring master event data).

I was trying FindItem with a restriction like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
         <mes:ItemShape>
            <typ:BaseShape>AllProperties</typ:BaseShape>
         </mes:ItemShape>
         <mes:Restriction>
            <typ:IsEqualTo>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:RecurringMasterItemId"/>
               <typ:FieldURIOrConstant>
               <typ:Constant Value="AQMkAD[snip]AAAAA=="/>
               </typ:FieldURIOrConstant>
            </typ:IsEqualTo>
         </mes:Restriction>
         <mes:ParentFolderIds>
           <typ:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar"/>
         </mes:ParentFolderIds>
      </mes:FindItem>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but this returns:
The 'FieldURI' attribute is invalid - The value 'item:RecurringMasterItemId' is invalid according to its datatype (types:UnindexedFieldURIType) - The Enumeration constraint failed.
(I also know the ChangeKey for the recurring appointment and tried that, with the same error)

How should this be fixed to make it work?

BTW. I know about retrieving occurrences with GetItem like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:GetItem>
         <mes:ItemShape>
            <typ:BaseShape>IdOnly</typ:BaseShape>
         </mes:ItemShape>
         <mes:ItemIds>
            <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="AQMkAD[snip]AAAA==" InstanceIndex="1"/>
            <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="AQMkAD[snip]AAAA==" InstanceIndex="2"/>
            <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="AQMkAD[snip]AAAA==" InstanceIndex="3"/>
         </mes:ItemIds>
      </mes:GetItem>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Then, I could retrieve StartDate and loop through them, but there is no way I can predict the InstanceIndex range that might apply.

Thanks in advance,
Jan

Comment: If anyone has EWS Managed API code to do this that might also help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like this is possible.

I have now resorted to using GetItem, retrieving 50 occurrences at a time.

This returns a list of GetItemResponseMessages containing either:

- Succesful occurrence retrievals
- ErrorCalendarOccurrenceIndexIsOutOfRecurrenceRange responsecode indicating that we have reached the last occurrence
- Other 'real' errors
- ErrorCalendarOccurrenceIsDeletedFromRecurrence responsecode indicating that the occurrence was deleted

So I just loop until I have found the proper date, reached ErrorCalendarOccurrenceIndexIsOutOfRecurrenceRange, or reached a maximum number of calls set in my code.